# How to make post request as form-data with Get x package in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

Hi i need to send signup body as form-data in flutter with getx.

here is my model clas

```
class SignupBody {
int? responseStatus;
String? message;
String? userId;
String? name;
String? email;
String? role;
String? country;
File? photo;
String? university;
List<String>? qualification;
List<String>? interests;

SignupBody(
  {this.responseStatus,
  this.message,
  this.userId,
  this.name,
  this.email,
  this.role,
  this.country,
  this.photo,
  this.university,
  this.qualification,
  this.interests});  
}
```

i need to post this body as form-data how can i post as form-data ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the dart HTTP package and convert your class `SignupBody` into JSON:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = Uri.parse('https://example.com/whatsit/create');
var response = await http.post(url, body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');

print(await http.read(Uri.parse('https://example.com/foobar.txt')));
```

Source:

https://pub.dev/packages/http

(If that is the best choice, depends on your setup which you did not describe in your question. If you use Firebase use `FlutterFire`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dio package to send formData.

- First make formdata

  ```
  var formData = await formDataMap(
    checkbox: checkbox,
    taskDetail: _task,
    pageNumber: _currentQuestion.value,
    valueString: value,
    valueType: valueType,
    formFieldInstanceID:
    task.formFields[_currentQuestion.value].formFieldInstanceId,
  );
  ```
- Then add it in data parameter of dio_client
  Example

  ```
   _dio.putUri(
   Uri.parse(uri),
   data: data,
  ```

  );

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FormData(map)` from get package.

```
FormData formdata = FormData(map);
post(url, formdata);
```